Do we believe in objective morality?
Do we believe in objective morality? Meaning that even if G-d didn’t exist c”v the world would still have morals? Or do we believe that all sense of morality and goodness comes as a result of there being G-d

How could G-d not exist?

I think the point is that certain people or groups change the definition of right and wrong.  God saying it makes it concrete.

A basic of belief (see Maimonides' first laws in his Code) is that without G-d, there is no world or existence, so the question is moot. The right way to phrase the question is would right and wrong exist without G-d commanding us.

The question seems confused. What if God established a morality that was different in different circumstances? Would that be a divine non-objective morality?
